# Django custom commands not showing up on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I’m having a problem when using django custom commands on Heroku.
On my local machine, the custom command appears in help if I run ./manage.py help and running ./manage.py deletedphotos runs it too.
All the **init**.py files are there and the settings are also correct, i.e. there are not  major config differences between my local and Heroku instances.

Now, when I put it on Heroku, it does not show up. All my other non-default commands are there: ping_google that comes from installing sitemap.xml support and commands for south migrations. But for some reason, my self written commands do not show up.

I’ve also sent a support request to Heroku, but haven’t heard back from them in a few days, so I thought I’d post here as well, maybe someone has had any similar problems.

The deletedphotos.py file contents are pretty much like this if that matters anything:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from foo.app.models import *

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Delete photos from S3'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        deleted_photos = Photo.objects.filter(deleted=True).exclude(large='', small='', thumb='')
        self.stdout.write('Found %s photos\n' % str(len(deleted_photos)))
```

I’ve tried checking all the correct python paths etc, but not 100% if I’m not missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was actually able to find a solution. The INSTALLED_APPS had my local app referenced, but for some reason it was not working as intended.

My app is in: /name/appname/ and having 'name.appname' in INSTALLED_APPS was working fine in local setup.

Yet, on Heroku, I had to change the reference to just 'appname' in INSTALLED_APPS and all started working magically.

Answer (score 1):

Your home directory needs to be on your Python path. A quick and unobtrusive way to accomplish that is to add it to the **PYTHONPATH** environment variable (which is generally **/app** on the Heroku Cedar stack).

Add it via the **heroku config** command:

```
$ heroku config:add PYTHONPATH=/app
```

That should do it! For more details:
http://tomatohater.com/2012/01/17/custom-django-management-commands-on-heroku/

Comment: When I need to run manage.py command on Heroku I just type `heroku run python manage.py shell' (or any other commands, migrate and such). So what is this your_app/manage.py ? Following your tutorial didn't help me. What do you mean by 'your_app'?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. It just depends on where your manage.py is located. If yours is not in a subdirectory, then you don't need the your_app part.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, found the answer here: [Django Management Command ImportError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032858/django-management-command-importerror)

I was missing an `__init__.py` file in my management folder. After adding it everything worked fine.

Example:

```
qsl/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            news.py
    jobs/
        __init__.py
        news.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```