# Django Management Command ImportError

Tags: python, django, importerror, pythonpath

I have problem with imported module into my `qsl/management/commands/<customcommand>.py` file.
in fact, my app structure is :

```
qsl/management/commands/ : dir for my management commands
qsl/management/jobs/ : dir for my mangement jobs
```

jobs are python classes that contains the job i want to be done in the coresponding command

e.g:

```
news command in qsl/management/commands/ imports news job in qsl/management/jobs/
```

my error when i want to execute `python manage.py news` is an `importerror : no module named management.jobs.news`

Answer (score 10):

Make sure that all the folders have a `__init__.py` in them so that they can be imported as modules.
The structure is described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Something like this for your structure:

```
qsl/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            news.py
    jobs/
        __init__.py
        news.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

Comment: thanks,yes, it's the sctruture here. all folders have a __init__.py by

Comment: If the answer solved your problem you should mark it as the best answer by clicking the tick mark to the left...

Comment: no, i just response to your question. but the problem still existing!

Comment: No, your answer did not help me. all folders already had __init__.py files.

Answer (score 0):

If isn’t not a typo in file/directory structure then perhaps you are pip installing and having the issue?

In your `setup.py` under your `packages=[]` make sure you include

both `qsl.management` and `qsl.management.commands`.  This solved the issue for me.