# Custom Django management commands not appearing on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

When I do `python manage.py` locally, I get a list of management commands that includes my custom commands.  When I do `heroku run python manage.py` I get a list of management commands that includes everything but my custom commands.  Why?

I've read [Django custom commands not showing up on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294363/django-custom-commands-not-showing-up-on-heroku) and have neither of the problems described in the two answers.

**Update**: The commands of other, 3rd party, apps are showing up.  For example, all of djcelery's commands are available.

**Update**: For some reason my management directory is not appearing on heroku...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the following lines in my `.slugignore` file:

```
# Ignore all management scripts
*.sh
```

Seems the hash mark was not interpreted as a comment and was causing Heroku to ignore the management directory...